# OpenStack on Centos 6 vs ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, benchmark, openstack

I want to install [open stack](http://openstack.org) on centos 6 but the documentation and most of the tutorials go on with Ubuntu. I want to know if there are any particular advantages of installing open stack on  Ubuntu? Is there any suitable benchmarking tool available so that I can measure the performance of open stack on both Ubuntu and centos? Any advice if I decide to go with Centos?

Comment: Use the distribution that you're most comfortable with.  Looks like the documentation has RHEL 6 covered, too; use those instructions if you go with CentOS.

Comment: Usually I have seen administrators doing such things keeping in mind Red hat or Centos. I am guessing that since rackspace did this with ubuntu they would have a good reason for it. [Doc](http://docs.openstack.org/diablo/openstack-compute/starter/content/) says nothing about red hat though I found a wiki page describing an approach towards using red hat/centos.

Comment: Sure it does, just not in the condensed starter guide (which states on the table of contents that it only covers Ubuntu).  See [here](http://docs.openstack.org/diablo/openstack-compute/admin/content/installing-openstack-compute-on-rhel6.html).

Comment: ah! I'll go through it. Any benchmarking tool you can suggest or should I go with anything and it won't matter a lot?

Comment: Yeah, just go with what you're comfortable with.  If there's any performance difference, I'd expect it to be extremely minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been testing it on centos6 first tried the openstack repository then the griddynamics repository. Both seem to be working make sure you install yum priorities and set them on the repositories.

I dont think you will see much difference in the benchmarking. Just choose the distro you are most familiar with.